# Pandoc: change headline style in DOCX output

Tags: title, docx, pandoc

I would like to convert this Markdown:

```
# headline 1

My text

## headline 2
```

To have something like this in DOCX:

```
<customStyleTitle1>headline 1</customStyleTitle1>
<text>My text</text>
<customStyleTitle2>headline 2</customStyleTitle2>
```

To be clear, I would like to create custom style and to apply it to my titles.

I know there is the option `--reference-docx` but I don't know how to apply the styles to my headlines...

Answer (score 4):

Use Word itself to modify the styles.

Make a copy of reference.docx and put it in your data directory as described in the pandoc manual. Open the copy with Word and edit the Title style (Format -> Style…). When you tell pandoc to use the modified reference.docx, it will take its styles from that document rather than its default.

For a list of docx styles that pandoc uses, see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/pandoc-discuss/IFVIruMo5bA).